# Entity framwork linq include() last 2 records in 1 to many

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to find a way to only get the last 2 records in a 1 to many relationship in entity framework 6. 
I have 3 model objects.
Product, price and stock.
A product has a list of price and stock objects.
I need the last record to show the current price and stock and the second to last to compare for price difference.

Basically im trying to find a way to do this:

`var products = ProductManager.Instance.SelectAll(db)
                .Include(a => a.ProductPrices.Reverse().Take(2))
                .Include(a => a.ProductStock.Last());`

But this will throw a runtime error.

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: @Rhumborl The following error is thrown: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve the issue, so not putting as an answer yet, but it looks like `Reverse()` isn't supported by Entity Framework - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx#sectionSection3). Instead you should use `OrderByDescending()`, e.g. `.Include(a => a.ProductPrices.OrderByDescending(p => p.PriceId).Take(2))`

Comment: @Rhumborl I will try your solution monday. I prefer to use the include() approach because it looks much cleaner. But if that doesn't work ill just stick with the joins.

Comment: @Rhumborl OrderByDescending will throw me the same error. I don't think you can modify the include. I will use Giorgi's solution instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest this solution:

```
var products = (from pm in ee.ProductManager

                        join pp in ee.ProductPrices on pm.ProductID equals pp.ProductID into temppp
                        from ppp in temppp.OrderByDescending(c => c.ProductID).Take(2)

                        join ps in ee.ProductStock on pm.ProductID equals ps.ProductID into tempps
                        from pps in tempps.OrderByDescending(c => c.ProductID).Take(1)

                        select new { pm, ppp, pps }
                            ).ToList();
```